# How do I properly get the state data set with nuxtServerInit in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a situation where I get data from api in nuxtServerInit and write it to the store's state variable like so

```
 let categoriesService = new Categories(this.$axios);
    categoriesService.current().then((resp) => {
      if (resp.data.success) {
        const navCategoryRoutes = resp.data.items
          .filter((item) => {
            return item.label !== "" && item.label;
          })
          .map((item) => {
            item.label = item.label.toLowerCase();
            item.isSelected = false;
            item.url = "/category/" + item.name + "/";
            return item;
          });
        commit("nav/setNavCategoryRoutes", navCategoryRoutes);
      }
    });
```

I log it in the setter to the console and I can see that below the assignment declaration and I can see it's there

```
  state: {
    categoryRoutes: [
      [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object]
    ]
  },
```

In the getter, however, it's always an empty array ;/

```
export const getters = {
  getNavCategoryRoutes(state) {
    console.log({ getter: state });
    return state.categoryRoutes;
  },
};
```

```
  getter: {
    categoryRoutes: []
  }
```

and in the file where I try to use it obviously it is empty as well

```
    categories() {
      console.log({
        header: this.$store.getters["nav/getNavCategoryRoutes"],
      });
      return this.$store.getters["nav/getNavCategoryRoutes"];
    },
```

I have tried to fetch it in computed property:

```
  computed: {
    categories() {
      return this.$store.getters["nav/getNavCategorysRoutes"];
    },
  },
```

and in the mounted lifecycle method:

```
  mounted() {
    this.categories = this.$store.getters["nav/getNavCategoryRoutes"];
  },
```

But the problem is earlier in the getter I think, I just don't know what am I doing wrong ;/ this getter is no different from the working ones. Would you please point me in the proper direction, I am out of ideas about what to do with that, thanks a lot.

Comment: In your getter, have you tried returning ```state.nav.categoryRoutes```?

Comment: This produces cannot read properties of undefined error

Comment: Ok, can you please share a little more info? Your nuxtServerInit method, and also make sure it’s in your index.js store and not some other name spaced location?

Answer (score 0):

To get data in nuxtServerInit, add nuxtServerInit to actions:

```
nuxtServerInit({ commit }) {
 // get data then commit mutation
})
```